# Firebase Admin SDK - Error: "Credential implementation provided to initializeApp()"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to delete the user from Firebase by uid field. For this I'm trying below code.

> Constant.js

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "private_key_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "private_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "client_email": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "XXXX"
  }),
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXX"
});

export const firebaseAdmin = admin;
```

> Auth.js

```
firebaseAdmin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);

  });
```

In above Example. It always goes into catch and display the error.

> Error
>
> Error deleting user: Error: "Credential implementation provided to
>   initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid
>   **Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse
>   access token response: Error: Error while making request: incorrect
>   header check. Error code: Z_DATA_ERROR"."**
>   FirebaseError
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:161518:17
>     PrefixedFirebaseError
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:161575:17  FirebaseAppError
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:161620:17
>     cachedTokenPromise_
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:157209:15

Comment: A lot of the time this is because your server's clock is out of sync. See if that's the case.

Comment: Quick side note: You should avoid having your access credentials in your source code. Many implementations use a json file that is not committed to git to avoid this. Make sure the Admin SDK has been updated to the latest version as Z_DATA_ERROR suggests that gzip is at fault. If this doesn't work, you can explore the alternative  method using an [OAuth refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#using_an_oauth_20_refresh_token).